# Qual è il significato di "rifatta" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Dice che, a guardar bene tra le macerie, si vedono ancora schegge di legno dorato, chissà, forse le seggioline della sala da ballo, che mia madre non ha voluto portar via – “roba **rifatta**, non val la pena”.

La frase si riferisce alle macerie della casa dei nonni della narratrice, distrutta durante la guerra.

Ho cercato il [significato di "rifatto" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rifatto/). Tuttavia, non capisco cosa vuol dire la madre della narratrice qualificando di "roba rifatta" le seggioline della sala da ballo. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: A me fa venire in mente le fabbriche “di mobili antichi” o “di mobili in stile” che ho visto durante il giro turistico di ieri. Nel caso in esame, la madre potrebbe voler dire che si tratta di mobili finto-antichi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uno dei significati di ***[rifare](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/R/rifare.php)*** è:

> - Imitare, contraffare, rappresentare o raffigurare copiando fedelmente: *ha rifatto la casa di quando era piccolo; rifece un quadro di Caravaggio* (Hoepli)

- La made si riferisce  al fatto che non si tratta di mobili originali, ma rifatti imitando  uno stile, per cui di poco valore.